# Wine: How to create link a directory outside of its virtual C drive?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, wine

I am using Wine with Bottles. I created a "bottle", and it is using some directory under `~/.var/app....` as a virtual C drive. That is, if I put some file there, in Wine applications, the files appear as if they are in the C drive.

Since I could delete the "bottle" or reinstall Linux, etc, I do not want to put permanent data into that virtual C drive. I want to create a data somewhere safe, and link that directory under the virtual C drive directory. I created a symbolic link, and under Linux, that symbolic link seemed to work. However, if I open Windows File Explorer within Wine, the symbolic link directory does not show up. I thought maybe I need to create a "hard" link, but `ln` says that I cannot create a hard-link directory.

There is no way to create a directory link and let Wine follow the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work with wine very often, but I feel like I remember there being a Z:\ drive in wine, that is basically a remount of /.

But on the topic of "remount":

You should be able to bind mount any directory you want to whereever you want in your bottle.

E.g:

```bash
mount -o bind /var/myveryimportantstuff /path/to/your/bottles/importantfiles
```

Keep in mind that ^this^ is only temporary. If you want to make it permanent you have to create a new entry in `/etc/fstab` like this

```
/var/myveryimportantstuff /path/to/your/bottles/importantfiles none defaults,bind 0 0
```